# Inheritance of symfony2 translations

Tags: php, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.1, symfony-sonata

I am using SonataUserBundle for extending user managing functionality. Also i use this bundle model file as base for registration form in frontend. On the another hand i want to add some other translations to FOSUserBundle.pl.yml - for example for firstname and lastname.

New form is defined in src/Application/Sonata/UserBundle/Form/Type/RegistrationFormType.php

So how and where should i create translation file to extend already defined translation?

I tried to put it in Application/Sonata/UserBundle/Resources/translations/Application/Sonata/UserBundle/Resources/translations/ApplicationSonataUserBundle.pl.yml but it was not working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put modified `FOSUserBundle.pl.yml` in `app/Resources/translations` folder. See [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#translation-locations-and-naming-conventions) .